# Java regex problem with two or more signs

Tags: java, regex

I want to write a regex pattern which find strings containts only: p, q, r, ^, v and ~ signs, but also implication and equivalence, represented by two (=>) or three (<=>) signs. How can I do that?

For example that pattern:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[(=>)(<=>)]*");
```

Matches strings that contains: `(, =, >, <, )` signs, whereas I want to write a pattern which contains only `*=>*` and `*<=>*`.

Comment: Can you give more details, what did you already try? What was not working? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Right, done :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your pattern to be like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(p|q|r|v|\\^|~|=>|<=>)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(yourString);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
}
```

The issue you had is that `[...]` is a *character* set, meaning that it matches against the individual characters you have inside the braces, rather than the full string.

Answer (score 0):

Your current pattern is a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and could also be written as `[()<>=]*`

You can update your pattern by adding p, q, r, ^, v and ~ signs to the character class instead `[pqrv^~]`.

To match either `=>` or `<=>` you can make `<` optional using a question mark.

The full pattern could be written using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) an a non capturing group:

```
(?:[pqrv^~]|<?=>)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/B494gc/1)

The code could look like

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:[pqrv^~]|<?=>)");
```